# Which Dynamic .NET language makes more sense to learn, Iron Ruby or Iron Python?

Tags: .net, ironpython, ironruby, dynamic-language-runtime, dynamic-languages

I'd like to take some time to learn more about dynamic languages built on top of the DLR and I'm not sure which language would be better to learn.

Having limited time, I really only have time to look learn one of them.

Any opinions on which of the two (Iron Ruby or Iron Python) would be more useful in the long run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is 'Which language runs better on the CLR,' then right now, IronPython wins hands down.

For the long term though, 'which language will teach me more, and serve me better in my career as a programmer', I would definitely say IronRuby (this would be true of CPython vs CRuby also)

Ruby will expose you to more 'concepts' than python does, due to it being more liberal in how it handles things like lambda functions, code blocks, eval, and so on.

Anyway, this is probably going to descend into a flame-war. Sorry

Comment: Brilliant answer, hadn't thought about exposure to more concepts. That's how I feel as I learn Ruby coming from Java: it's got new stuff that I've never seen.

Comment: More concepts? But Python has lambdas, first class functions, and eval. I think the ruby built-ins are more likely to use lambdas/code blocks than python's though.

Answer (score 5):

Without getting into the relative merits of the languages (which would be an entire pissing contest in itself), IronPython (stable 1.1.1, beta 2.0) is further along in development than IronRuby (alpha)

Answer (score 3):

Whichever you choose, take a look at [IronEditor](http://www.codeplex.com/IronEditor) -- it's great for playing around. I'm currently using it to try and pick up those languages myself...

Answer (score 2):

I would go for IronPython at the moment since there are plenty of books/information around for it ([IronPython In Action](http://www.manning.com/foord/) is just getting finished up).

I would personally learn IronRuby because I prefer the way Ruby works over Python and since it's one of the same then choose which language you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to mention that there is also a DLR version of Javascript(JScript), which is my personal fav.   If you are looking for a new language to learn for dlr use, I'd suggest ironpython as mentioned, it is farther along in terms of the dlr.  Python is also fairly popular outside the dlr for gui programming, and offers Django for mvc web apps.

This is purely subjective, but I think that ruby popularity is waning a bit.  In the long run I feel it will be like perl, used and respected, but a  drop in the bucket compared to other options.  I happen to really like ruby (and perl), but wouldn't suggest it as a new path for your intended purpose.

Comment: Perl is actually quite popular as long as your bucket is "programming," and not just "web programming".

Comment: @Sean McMillan, there isn't a DLR version of Perl though, that I am aware of in any case... MS pretty much dropped Managed JScript support pretty early on, there's an IronJS implementation gaining speed too.  I don't think the DLR will make much more progress, MS has re-assigned all the DLR developers. :(

Answer (score 0):

As other said, IronPython is more stable and mature, and you can find more samples and lots of regular Python code that you will be able to try out.

IronRuby is great but beware: to try it you need to get the code right from the SVN and compile it by yourself. Or you can download the [Dynamic Silverlight SDK](http://www.codeplex.com/sdlsdk/) and get it that way, but you'll have to spend sometime learning this environment also.